# Eloqua Form Validation Message using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, eloqua

we have a form with a multi Picklist field and will have a validation message that says "Please select at least one". The problem is that it is not a required field and we are putting this message because we just want to instruct the registrants to select one before submitting. The validation message should disappear if the multi picklist is hidden.

I would like to ask if this is possible in Eloqua?

I created the following JavaScript code:

var multipleSelectMenu = document.getElementsByClassName(`multipleSelectMenu`); //checkbox items

 

//create a validation message element
var validationMessage = document.createElement(`div`);
validationMessage.classList.add(`validation-message`);
validationMessage.textContent = `Please select at least one item.`;

 

//add the validation message element to the body of the document
document.body.appendChild(validationMessage);

 

//select all checkboxes
for (var i = 0; i  0){
            document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
            validationMessage.style.display = `none`;
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
            validationMessage.style.display = `block`;
        }

    });
}
   

var multipleSelectMenu = document.getElementsByClassName(`multipleSelectMenu`); //checkbox items

 

//create a validation message element
var validationMessage = document.createElement(`div`);
validationMessage.classList.add(`validation-message`);
validationMessage.textContent = `Please select at least one item.`;

 

//add the validation message element to the body of the document
document.body.appendChild(validationMessage);

 

//select all checkboxes
for (var i = 0; i  0){
            document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
            validationMessage.style.display = `none`;
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
            validationMessage.style.display = `block`;
        }

    });
}

I expected it to create a paragraph message that will be the validation message but it made the whole multipicklist disappear instead.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could you please format your code and fix the for conditions and iterators?

'''